# display different string in UI

Tags: javascript, html, angular, string

I have a string in this format

> strb= str1+ ' ' + str2

```
  <span>{{strb}}</span>
```

How can I change this to display it backwards

Comment: What is your framework? You can use split

Comment: Please tag with angular or angularjs where necessary

Answer (score 2):

You can split your string at `,` to get first name and last name separately. This will literally cut away the parts you pass as a prop to your `.split()` function and return an array with the leftover pieces of your string.

```
const names = fullName.split(', '); //['BROWN', 'MARY'];
const firstName = names[1]; //'MARY'
const lastName = names[0]; //'BROWN'
```